# IApp is leaking memory

Tags: objective-c, memory-leaks, afnetworking-2

I ran my app through instruments to see if there were any memory leaks. I have noticed two leaks showing up. One leak only happens at start up which is this:

**Line 4 is the offending bit of code here:**

```
    static id (*_old_UIStoryboard_instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier_)(UIStoryboard *self, SEL _cmd, NSString *identifier);
static id _UIStoryboard_instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier_(UIStoryboard *self, SEL _cmd, NSString *identifier)
{
    id ret = _old_UIStoryboard_instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier_(self, _cmd, identifier);

    if ([[self delegate] respondsToSelector:@selector(storyboard:didInstantiateViewController:withIdentifier:)])
        [[self delegate] storyboard:self didInstantiateViewController:ret withIdentifier:identifier];

    return ret;
}
```

The biggest leak I have is actually in `AFNetworking`s code. I am not sure if its something I am doing that causes it though. In the class file: `AFURLSessionManager.m`

```
- (instancetype)initWithSessionConfiguration:(NSURLSessionConfiguration *)configuration {
    self = [super init];
    if (!self) {
        return nil;
    }

    if (!configuration) {
        configuration = [NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration];
    }

    self.sessionConfiguration = configuration;

    self.operationQueue = [[NSOperationQueue alloc] init];
    self.operationQueue.maxConcurrentOperationCount = 1;

    self.session = [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration:self.sessionConfiguration delegate:self delegateQueue:self.operationQueue];

    self.responseSerializer = [AFJSONResponseSerializer serializer];

    self.securityPolicy = [AFSecurityPolicy defaultPolicy];

    self.reachabilityManager = [AFNetworkReachabilityManager sharedManager];

    self.mutableTaskDelegatesKeyedByTaskIdentifier = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];

    self.lock = [[NSLock alloc] init];
    self.lock.name = AFURLSessionManagerLockName;

    [self.session getTasksWithCompletionHandler:^(NSArray *dataTasks, NSArray *uploadTasks, NSArray *downloadTasks) {
        for (NSURLSessionDataTask *task in dataTasks) {
            [self addDelegateForDataTask:task completionHandler:nil];
        }

        for (NSURLSessionUploadTask *uploadTask in uploadTasks) {
            [self addDelegateForUploadTask:uploadTask progress:nil completionHandler:nil];
        }

        for (NSURLSessionDownloadTask *downloadTask in downloadTasks) {
            [self addDelegateForDownloadTask:downloadTask progress:nil destination:nil completionHandler:nil];
        }
    }];

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(taskDidResume:) name:AFNSURLSessionTaskDidResumeNotification object:nil];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(taskDidSuspend:) name:AFNSURLSessionTaskDidSuspendNotification object:nil];

    return self;
}
```

These lines from the above method show up as leaking memory - every time this method is called:

```
  if (!configuration) {
    configuration = [NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration];
}

 self.operationQueue = [[NSOperationQueue alloc] init];
```

The worse one showing the most leaks:

```
 self.session = [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration:self.sessionConfiguration delegate:self delegateQueue:self.operationQueue];
```

And this:

```
self.mutableTaskDelegatesKeyedByTaskIdentifier = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
```

Then the last one:

```
 self.securityPolicy = [AFSecurityPolicy defaultPolicy];
```

How can I solve these leaks? Also, I would like to know why are they are leaking memory and not just the solution, would like to know more about these cases.

Answer (score 0):

try to use in blocks weak_self, not self, for example:

```
__weak ClassName *weak_self = self;
    [self.session getTasksWithCompletionHandler:^(NSArray *dataTasks, NSArray *uploadTasks, NSArray *downloadTasks) {
        for (NSURLSessionDataTask *task in dataTasks) {
            [weak_self addDelegateForDataTask:task completionHandler:nil];
        }

        for (NSURLSessionUploadTask *uploadTask in uploadTasks) {
            [weak_self addDelegateForUploadTask:uploadTask progress:nil completionHandler:nil];
        }

        for (NSURLSessionDownloadTask *downloadTask in downloadTasks) {
            [weak_self addDelegateForDownloadTask:downloadTask progress:nil destination:nil completionHandler:nil];
        }
    }];
```

Comment: Thanks I will make that change and see how it affect the leaks.